# multi-threading access to synchronized statement

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement thread-safe operations in Android. I'm using a `SyncAdapter` to send data to a server. The problem is that the user can modify the same data that is being sent, after the data is sent, I compare the current stored data(probably modified) with the one that was just sent.

I want to avoid this:

```
(SyncAdapter thread) - data sent to server
(SyncAdapter thread) - comparing data
(SyncAdapter thread) - result: the data was not modified
(UI thread) - main thread updates the database
(SyncAdapter thread) - set the data to a sent state.
```

Now, the database has data that is not going to be sent

To solve that, I implemented a synchronized statement. First of all this is my lock:

```
public class Lock {

     public final static Lock lock = new Lock();

     private Lock() {}

}
```

This is code from the `SyncAdapter.onPerformSync()`, as you can see sleep the thread to be able to test it:

```
synchronized (Lock.lock) {
    Log.d(TAG, "inside synchronized block...");
    if (isDataUnchanged()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "data compared...");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        // update data state to 'sent'
        provider.update(mUri, cValues, null, null);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "exits synchronized block...");
}
```

from the UIThread something similar:

```
synchronized (Lock.lock) {
    Log.d("UIThread", "inside synchronized");
    ...    
    getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().update(uri, cv, null, null);
}
```

But when I test it, I see the UIThread enters the synchronized statement when it shouldn't. Or at least that's what I expect since the lock is the same for both statements.

```
D/SyncAdapter﹕ inside synchronized block...
D/SyncAdapter﹕ Data is the same
D/SyncAdapter﹕ data compared...
D/UIThread﹕ inside synchronized
D/SyncAdapter﹕ exits synchronized block...
```

**Edit**

ok, think I got it, I just realize the SyncAdapter is running in a separate process than the app. That must be the reason the locks are not the same.

```
Lock@415e69f0
Lock@417c6e88
```

**Edit 2**

The app and SyncAdapter running in different processes was the cause. I moved the SynAdapter execution to the app process, changing the [android:process](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html) attribute of the SyncAdapter `Service`, now the synchronized blocks work as expected.

Altought I would like to know if there is a way to synchronize across processes, because it would be better for the app's assigned memory. Maybe passing the lock to the adapter in the bundle, but i'm not sure it would work, or maybe AIDL, Messenger. I'm not sure.

Comment: Your exit log is outside the block. It can be printed at any time, out of order.

Comment: oh you are right, but it's a mistake while writing the question, the log output is valid

Comment: I doubt it. More likely the same mistake is in the code. Check that you're running the code you think you're running.

Comment: @EJP It seems that was the reason I was getting different instances of thelock, I edited the question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use MemoryFile to synchronize across processes.

1. use two shared memory sharedmemory1, sharedmemory2.
2. process1 read only sharedmemory1 and write only sharedmemory2.
   process2 read only sharedmemory2 and write only sharedmemory1.
3. Any process should write sharedmemory which it can write at first, and then check the sharedmemory which it can read before the process want to write synchronize field.

I am not sure whether this suggestion is effective. Just an idea, hope to help you.